# Storing Boolean Values In SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm designing a SQL datbase table and a couple of the columns need to hold either a 1 or 0 (true or false).  I define the columns to be of type binary(1), but now I don't know how to insert a true or false value into the database.  inserting "true" or "1" doesn't work (it says either int or bool cannot be converted to binary)...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `bit` data type instead for your column. Then you can insert true/false directly.

Comment: Sounds good.  Now, what is the binary data type?  I thought binary meant 0 or 1.

Comment: binary allows you to store raw data, such as images or word documents. well anything really...

Comment: Huh, interesting.  I'll have to learn more about that some time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use bit

This accepts the strings "true" and "false".

It also maps directly to the c# boolean type which is useful

Answer (score 3):

Since there there is no Boolean in SQL server you can just use `bit` and set it to 0/1

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what database you are using. E.g., for SQL Server you can use bit and then set it to true using an integer 1. For Access, you can use a boolean and set it to True/False.